# Creating Movement for an Old School Dungeon Crawler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having some trouble getting my playercontroller script to recognize tag "Wall". I want the collider to hit the wall and bounce back in rigid motion or even not hit the wall in the first place.

This is what I have

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

  Vector3 pos;                                // For movement
  public float speed = 7.0f;                         // Speed of movement
  public float movementRange = 2.0f;
  public Transform relativeTransform;

  IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles, float inTime)
  {
    var fromAngle = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
    {
      transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t);
      yield return null;
    }
  }

 

  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
  
  {
    if(gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
      GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position += -relativeTransform.forward * (movementRange);
      Debug.Log("You hit a wall!");
    }  
  }


  void Start()
  {
    pos = transform.position;          // Take the initial position
  }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Left
      pos += -relativeTransform.right * (movementRange);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Right
      pos += relativeTransform.right * (movementRange);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Up
      pos += relativeTransform.forward * (movementRange);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Down
      pos += -relativeTransform.forward * (movementRange);

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && transform.position == pos)
    {
      StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * -90, 0.8f));
    } //Rotate Left

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && transform.position == pos)
    {
      StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * 90, 0.8f));
    } //Rotate Right

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);    // Move there
  }

}
```

I have the playercontroller script attached to the main camera, with a rigid body and capsule collider. I am at a loss at the moment. Any help would be awesome.

The script is not recognizing the wall tag and not sending the message to the debug log.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Rubber ducking helped!

I needed to add collision.gameobject to fix the collision!

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
  
  {
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
      pos += -relativeTransform.forward * (movementRange);
      Debug.Log("You hit a wall!");
    }  
  }
```